# Can I create a collision mask?

Tags: c#, xna

At the moment, I check collision between two objects by seeing if any of the corners of the square sprites intersect.

I was going to check if the pixels intersected AND they were not transparent pixels on the target. However this won't work for letting me walk behind a tree.

Instead, I wonder if there's an easy way to use a mask, possibly stored within the .png that I can use to check. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to use the image's alpha channel as mask, assuming you want only the non-transparent pixels to clip. Try using `Texture2D.GetData` to get a desired framgent of the image and check for `.A` alpha component's value.

I think older games have separate monochrome textures for masks, and some even use 2-dimensional arrays of bits (or boolean). Of course this might be faster and consume less CPU resources, but will also be harder to implement.